# XPages JVM Error: err.PersistenceServiceResourceProvider.Errorwritingtopersistedcontenttor

Tags: jvm, xpages

We are running a Domino 8.5.3 and the server log is constantly issuing these errors:

> HTTP JVM:
>   !err.PersistenceServiceResourceProvider.Errorwritingtopersistedcontenttor!

We have not been able to isloate it to a particular page.  Eventually, the HTTP task will crash and we need to reboot the server and recompile all the databases on the server.  We are using the CKEditor to generate the HTML content.  You help would be most appreciated.

Comment: We've come across a couple of fringe cases that produces this exception and they involve CKEditor. Cases like uploading and embedding very large images (10mb). But these cases have not crashed the server. So, my best advise here would be to call this one with Lotus support.

Comment: Make sure that you have excluded that temp folder from virus scanning if you have that on your server.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen that error before but it reads like it might be something to do with asking the server to make a lot of data available to the xpages between calls to the server- effectively, session and application scope data.

Answer (score 0):

We used to get this exact error a lot which appeared to be caused by inline images uploaded via the CKEditor like Paul mentioned.

I don't know why but we fixed it by changing the directory domino uses for uploads via the 
xsp property   xsp.persistence.dir.xspupload    (formally xsp.upload.directory)

changing it to something like c:\temp rather than the windows default made the problem go away. could have been a co-incidence but may have been something in windows interfering